# Can I get the intrinsic dimensions of external-graphic?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

As per definition given by XSL-FO 1.1 it says that if the value is a percentage, the value of this property is the percentage applied to the intrinsic width.

```
<fo:external-graphic content-width="100%" content-height="100%">
  ...
</fo:external-graphic>
```

My question is: Can I get the intrinsic width and height of this object so that I can define custom dimensions based on some conditions e.g if larger then... ?

Comment: You can't get it directly in your XSLT, you need an external application to read the image and figure out its size.

Answer (score 0):

The `allowed-height-scale` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#allowed-height-scale) and `allowed-width-scale` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#allowed-width-scale) properties are meant to take care of that for you.

If you provide a set of allowed scale factors, the XSL formatter should pick the one that best fits with the other constraints on the graphic.

In this example, the graphic was scaled at 25% (158.75mm) to fit within the 210mm width of the page:

```
<fo:block><fo:external-graphic inline-progression-dimension.maximum="100%"
    allowed-width-scale="5% 10% 25% 50%" content-width="scale-down-to-fit"
    src="logo-antenna-2400x2400.png"/></fo:block>
```

I believe that the intent behind `allowed-height-scale` and `allowed-width-scale` is, firstly, so that raster images won't show Moiré effects from being rendered at random scales and, secondly, so that text in graphics can at least appear at a discrete range of sizes rather than appearing to be completely randomly sized because the graphics the text are in were randomly sized.

Comment: I have a very limited knowledge of xsl-fo but for some images, when the aspect ratio of the original image tends towards a certain value (practically when the image is much higher than wide e.g 700x3000) than I get an FOPException:  **No meaningful layout in block after many attempts...** Which I believe is a fop bug. Neither setting _content-height_ to _scale-down-to-fit_ nor the _allowed-height-scale_ seems to help this case. The only hack I've found is to set the height to a defined value wich respect  the normal ratio. So I have to know for which dimensions should I apply this constraint.

Comment: FOP does not implement `allowed-height-scale`, but it does say that it implements `content-height`.  See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html.  Since `content-height` is supposed to work, try `<fo:external-graphic src="..." max-width="100%" max-height="100%" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" content-width="scale-down-to-fit"/>`.  That should get you something that fits on a page.